# checkbox html not updating my variable status userscripte?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

i use an automatic translator for English..

I am looking to create a html GUI for a userscripte.
I use

```
mwin=open('','_self');
        mwin.parent.document.write(
```

in a JS function to add my GUI html, especially :

```
<label class='switch'>
      <input type='checkbox'id='auto_run' onchange="Update(this)">
      <span class='slider round'></span>
    </label>
```

and in my userscript y create a function :

```
function Update(checkboxElem){
if (checkboxElem.checked) {
    GM_setValue('auto-run','true')
} else {
GM_setValue('auto-run','false')
}
}
```

when i run the userscripte on the web page, the html GUI is well created, but when i change the checkbox's status, the last one does not seem to call my function. Why ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Because userscripts run in a sandbox. It's better to attach the listener explicitly in js: document.getElementById('auto_run').onclick = Update;

Comment: sorry, developer is not my job. If I understand correctly, it is preferable to detect the changemant directly from the userscript? do you have an example?
I do not know what to do
"document.getElementById ('auto_run'). onclick = Update;"